# Maximum length of sequence of non-coprimes of $N$ - least upper bound for Jacobsthal's function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I am looking at the length of the longest sequences of adjacent integers that are not coprime to $N$ for very large $N$.

Let $F_N$ be the set of integers less than $N$ which are not coprime with $N$:
$$
F_N = \{x : x \in \mathbb{N}, x \lt N , \gcd(x,N)=1\} 
$$
Let $g(N)$ be the length of the longest sequence of adjacent integers in $F_N$.

IE something like:
$$
g(N) = \max (i\in \mathbb{N}) : \exists a\in F_n : \forall b : a \le b \lt a+i, b\in F_N 
$$
What is the least upper bound on $g(N)$, i.e. the maximum length of a sequence of adjacent numbers in $F_N$?

Some direct calculation suggests that $g(N)$ steps up when $N$ is primorial, so if $P_i$ is the primorial sequence, then:
$$
\forall N \lt P_i, g(N) \lt g(P_i)
$$
I have no proof of this, but it suggests $g(P_i)$ may be useful in finding a least upper bound.

There are $N - \phi (N)$ non-coprimes of $N$ less than $N$ (where $\phi$ represents Euler's totient function, labelled 'phi' in the table below). The assumption that these are evenly spread giving $$g(N) \approx \frac N {\phi (N)}$$ is clearly wrong.

Better estimates (for the primorial values of $N$ only) seem to be: $$g(N) \approx 2 \log(N)$$ and $g(N) \approx$ twice the highest prime factor of $N$. However, these are untested outside the data below, and again I have no proof.

Below is a table of $g(N)$ and $\phi(N)$ of the primorials:

```
 N (Primorial)   Highest prime   phi (N)    g(N) 
 2               2               0          1    
 6               3               1          3    
 30              5               7          5    
 210             7               47         9    
 2310            11              479        13   
 30030           13              5759       21   
 510510          17              92159      25   
 9699690         19              1658879    33   
 300690390       21              49766399   39
```

Edit:

As Gerry Myerson kindly points out in the comments, $g(N)$ is similar to [Jacobsthal's function](http://oeis.org/wiki/Jacobsthal_function), $j(N)$ series [here](http://oeis.org/A048669) where $j(N) = g(N)+1$.

Several online sources point to a proof by H. Iwaniec in *'On the problem of Jacobsthal, Demonstratio Math. 11, 225–231, (1978)'* (original not available online) that: $$j(N) \ll \log \log (N)$$
Whilst this might be true in asymptotic terms, it's trivially not true for the primorials above, and the sequence appears closer to $\log (N)$ than $\log \log(N)$. So the question remains open.

Comment: The smallest factor of $N$ is not an upper bound: for $N = 6$, the smallest factor is $2$, but $g(6) = 3$ as there are three consecutive numbers in $F_6$, namely $2, 3, 4$.

Comment: Thanks - thus proving every sentence starting with the words 'clearly' is wrong. I've removed that bit.

Comment: Your statement should clearly read "Clearly, every sentence starting with the words 'clearly' is wrong."

Comment: $g(N)$ is tabulated at http://oeis.org/A058989 and some references are given.

Comment: I don't think that's $g(N)$ as the input to that sequence is the $N$'th prime. However, that does provide a link to [the Jacobsthal function](http://oeis.org/wiki/Jacobsthal_function) $j(N)$, and it seems $$j(N)=g(N)+1$$ This gives $$j(n) = O(log^2(N))$$but I'm not sure that's an upper bound let alone a least upper bound.

Comment: Oh, and thanks a lot for the reference!

Comment: It's been pointed out elsewhere that a l.u.b. for j(N) can be found as the interval on $[1,p\#]$ whose midpoint has modularity (0,0,0,...,1,-1) mod $(2,3,5,..., p_{k-1},p_k)$ and which has length $2p_{k-1}.$ Starting with $23\#$ the maximum may be larger than this (40 adjacent non-coprimes on $[1,23\#]).$

Comment: Also your table of the gaps measures them in a non-standard way (and 21 is not prime). If you add 1 to g(N) you can see more easily that the distance is $2p_{k-1}$ up until p=23. I think the OEIS ref. has a comment that your conjecture about primorials offering the largest gaps has been disproven but I haven't checked recently.